# How do I normalize data using microsoft access

Tags: ms-access

I currently have  a courses table that has a layout like below.

```
course_title, course_subject, course_number, instructor, course_id
```

I need to create a new table and then push over the instructor_id, so I can then access the table via a foreign key id for instructor, but I'm not sure how I would go about getting the data from the courses table over to the new tables such as instructor and also creating the instructor_id fields in the courses table. I hope this question makes sense. I'm importing a flat file from microsoft excel.

Comment: I'm confused with your question. Do you want to import a flat file and on that process look into an internal table to get a value based on a foreign key ?

Comment: From what I understand he just does not know how to modify a table and add another table with information on instructors. Voted to migrate to SU as this is not programming related at all.

Comment: So, did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Let's first define the schemas for our output tables. The `courses` table should be something like:

```
title varchar(100) not null
subject varchar(100) not null
[number] varchar(5) not null unique
id long primary key
instructor_id long not null references instructors (id)
```

And the `instructors` table should be:

```
id autoincrement primary key
[name] varchar(100) not null unique
```

Let's call your current table `courses_old`. I may be off by a bit but I'm sure you can adjust for your needs.

So the problem is to get from `courses_old` to `courses` and `instructors`. First we fill up the `instructors` table:

```
insert into instructors ([name])
select distinct instructor
from courses_old
```

Then we fill up `courses` with matching instructors from `instructors`:

```
insert into courses (
  title
, subject
, [number]
, id
, instructor_id
) select
  co.course_title
, co.course_subject
, co.course_number
, co.course_id
, i.id
from courses_old as co
inner join instructors as i
on co.instructor = i.[name]
```

That should do it. But obviously you need to verify. Finally, drop the `courses_old` table and compact the DB file!

Optionally, you can make `courses.id` an autoincrement field if you're willing to just give them all new IDs. That should be a simple adjustment to the above.